# How to grant a group permission to access c$ shares

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to centrally grant access to the c$ share of all our PCs to our IT active directory security group.  They often use this to check desktop shortcuts, etc.  Right now they have to use a domain admin credential each time they access a c drive.

Can I do this on a Windows 2003 Server domain controller running AD?  How?

Comment: What OS are you using on your workstations?

Comment: @Zoredache -Primarily Windows XP, with an increasing number of Win7 boxes.

Comment: @MAW74656 any updates? i need to achieve the same result... i need to figure out how to that, but for a single user...

Answer (score 4):

Havenard is right in that you probably shouldn't modify the NTFS permissions on the C: drive. What you can do is to use Restricted Groups in Group Policy to add the security group in question to the local Administrators group. That will give them the access they need to the C: drive.

Comment: Ok, so use a group policy restricted group.  Where would I apply this policy?  To the PC's in the domain, or to the user's I want to grant the access?

Comment: Restricted Groups is a Computer setting so you need to apply the GPO to the Computers.

Answer (score 2):

System's network shares like C$ and ADMIN$ should not be touched. Any changes will most likely be lost upon boot anyway.

If you want a user or a group to have access to your entire C driver, then create a new network share, name it "C" or whatever you want and share it with this group. Leave C$ alone.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as c$ gives acccess to the C drive, through which you can browse to the users desktop or My Documents folders.  Changes DO keep through reboot.

Comment: It gives access to the Administrator and to the Administrator alone. You can edit this settings, but they will not last. The system recreate this share with its system default settings upon reboot.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the share itself, as that already exists.  I'm just looking to grant permissions to access it.  If my domain admin account can access them, then I hope to grant just the c$ permission to the IT group.

Comment: @MAW74656 [*"Hidden administrative shares that are created by the computer (such as ADMIN$ and C$) can be deleted, but the computer re-creates them after you stop and restart the Server service or restart your computer"*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984) -- Don't try to alter the permissions on these admin shares. Either add your IT group to the local admins group or create a new share of C: and add the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @jscott -I understand this point, but I think perhaps you are not understanding what I'm trying to do here.  What is the mechanism that allows my domain admin account to access the c$ shares?  That is not a local setting, its something setup on the account in AD.  That is where I'm hoping to make a change.

Comment: @MAW74656 Your Domain Admin is a member of the Local Administrators group on all computers by virtue of the computers being a domain member.

Comment: So can I grant just that permission to another account/group?

Comment: Only members of the computer's local Administrators group will have access to the C$ and Admin$ shares -- this includes Domain Admins. Add the required domain groups to the local Administrators group on these computers and those groups will also have access.

Comment: @jscott -My requirement is to centrally do this, its not helpful if I have to change settings on every PC.

Comment: @MAW74656 There are many, centrally managed, ways to alter group memberships for domain-joined computers. See Joe's answer for one example using Restricted Groups.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some way to add and configure network shares using a .bat or .vbs script. If you figure out how you will sort that problem is 5 minutes.

Comment: But in any case if you are willing to access, delete and add shortcuts to your users' desktops, you will need to grant your IT team some sort of administration privilege anyway as regular users won't be able to modify other users personal files.

Comment: @Havenard -But thats my point, I'm trying to find out how to grant the least permissions needed to acheive the goal.

Answer (score -1):

From the sounds of the question you must be new at this stuff, anyway create a group for these IT people put them in it then add this group to the local administrators group.  This is not ideal, ideal would be to create a seperate account for each of these it people and to place that account in the IT Group and tell them not to use that account unless absolutely necessary.  Unfortunately this may be over you head in terms of understanding this.

Comment: So your answer to my question is "you can't do that centrally".  And I do NOT appreciate the rudeness.

Comment: yes you can do it centrally its called group enforcement via gpo's.

Comment: THAT should have been your answer.